# Number conversion into words

Tags: xetex, mapping, translate

I am working on a command that will convert/translate a number into a word. I am using a map to convert each number/character into a word.

```
\zztable{
\zzrow{zero}{0}
\zzrow{one}{1}
\zzrow{two}{2}
\zzrow{three}{3}
\zzrow{four}{4}
\zzrow{five}{5}
\zzrow{six}{6}
\zzrow{seven}{7}
\zzrow{eight}{8}
\zzrow{nine}{9}
}
```

However, it works fine when the number is in between 0 and 9. However, It does not work beyond 9 and I cannot manually map billion numbers. What is the automatic way to convert any number into a word. For example, 1022 should be “One Hundred and Twenty Two” NOT “One Zero Two Two”. Thank you. [I am using Xetex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you free to switch from Xe(La)TeX to Lua(La)TeX?

Comment: @Mico No sir. Actually, I am working on a group project and since the beginning we have been using Xetex. Therefore, I don't think it will be a good idea to switch at the last moment. Thank you.

Comment: I hope 1022 would not be One hundred twenty-four... ;-P (just joking)

Comment: @Rmano I don't understand your joke...

Comment: @projetmbc he means it should be One *Thousand* and Twenty Two, not *hundred*

Answer (score 8):

I think, you should use the `numspell` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{numspell}
\begin{document}
\numspell{122}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The package `fmtcount` does exactly what you need and more (including case handling, ordinals, etc...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \numberstringnum{1234}
    \item \Numberstringnum{123}
    \item \NUMBERstringnum{12}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The support for French is partially comparing to the one of `numspell`. In French, 1234 is written *"mille deux cent trente-quatre"* and not *"mille-deux-cent-trente-quatre"*.

Comment: @projetmbc The documentation of `fmtcount` says that after the 1990 spelling reform, hyphens are to be preferred throughout. You can say `\fmtcountsetoptions{french={dash or space=traditional}}` to avoid the hyphens. Wikipedia seems to concur: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforms_of_French_orthography#Hyphens

Comment: Damn! @egreg bit me to it... again! :-) although I had to have `\FCloadlang{french}` before the option worked. oh forget this, loading fmtcount after babel/polyglossia remove the need for the `FCloadlang` bit!

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the reference. A lot of people don’t use the recommendation of this reform even teachers in schools.

Comment: @projetmbc Anyway, good to know that you can get both ways