# Creating a custom section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am new to LaTeX. I would like to create a section numbering style using a custom list of character strings (primo, secundo, tertio…). My understanding is that I should do something like this:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\fnsymbol{section}}
```

Only not with `\fnsymbol` of course, but with another command inspired by it, generating my custom list instead of *, †, ‡…
The only problem is, I have no idea how to do that. I don't even know where to find the `\fnsymbol` command's source code. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome! Unless a class or a package redefines it, you can find the defintion of `\fnsymbol` in [`texdoc source2e`](https://texdoc.org/serve/source2e/0) (pp. 412ff). (You actually need to look for `\@fnsymbol` which contains the look-up table.) The `fnsymbol` is thought to be a small set of symbols for footnotes. Do you really want your sections not be numbered consecutive (1, 2, 3, …/A, B, C, …/I, II, III, …)?

Comment: To be clear, you want to replace a numbered system with a symbol system and use that system to number sections, correct? Or are you specifically looking at an ordinal numbering system instead of a cardinal numbering system for sections? In either case, I don't think messing with `\fnsymbol` is the way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For getting ordinal numbers written out there seem to be [two packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600013/16595) suited for that:

- [`fmtcount`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount)
- [`numspell`](https://ctan.org/pkg/numspell)

They have a slightly different interface in that `numspell` only works with actual numbers out of the box where `fmtcount` also has an interface for LaTeX counters.

The `fmtcount` package appears to have implicit support for genders (male, female, neutral) whereas `numspell` only has it for some explicit languages.

The Latin language is supported by `numspell` but not by `fmtcount`. (Your example seems to be in Latin.)

Here's a start for Italian. (Close enough?)

Note that since the same numbering scheme is used for the table of contents and for references

- the spacing has been adjusted with the `tocloft` package and
- the cases of references might not be right.

---

If you really want to create your own look-up table you will want to have a top-level command (for counters) and a low-level command that that does the actual work.

For this, you can use the `\NewNumberingScheme{<scheme>}{<look up>}` macro which sets up

- `\<scheme>` and
- `\@<scheme>`,

similar on how all the others work (`arabic`, `alph`, `roman`, `fnsymbol`)
where `\@<scheme>` takes one argument `#1` (the value of the counter) that needs to be used in `<look up>`.

I've added a small example `\weird` which you can then use as you would `\fnsymbol`:

```
\NewNumberingScheme{weird}{%
  \ifcase #1\relax zero\or eins\or second\or tertio\or viertes\or
     fifth\or another one\else more than six\fi}

\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\weird{subsection}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

% Adusting Table of Contents spacing
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftsecnumwidth{5em}
\setlength\cftsubsecnumwidth{5em}
\setlength\cftsubsubsecnumwidth{6em}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Ordinalstring{section}}

\usepackage{cleveref}

% custom numbering scheme
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\NewNumberingScheme[2]{%
  \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\newcommand*\expandafter\noexpand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{%
  \noexpand\expandafter\expandafter\noexpand\csname @#1\endcsname\noexpand\csname c@####1\endcsname}%
    \noexpand\newcommand*\expandafter\noexpand\csname @#1\endcsname}%
  \@tempa[1]{#2}}
\makeatother

\NewNumberingScheme{weird}{%
  \ifcase #1\relax zero\or eins\or second\or tertio\or viertes\or
     fifth\or another one\else more than six\fi}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\weird{subsection}}

%%% only for blindtext
\usepackage{blindtext}% ignore warning about italian not defined:
\makeatletter\renewcommand\blind@checklanguage{}\makeatother
%%%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\section{test}
\label{test}
This is \cref{test}.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will also be dependent on the class used since `memoir` for example has its own `\ordinal` macro.

Answer (score 1):

Define your sequence of strings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mynumbering}{m}{%
  \ExpandArgs{c}\@mynumbering{c@#1}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\@mynumbering}{m}
 {
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {1}{primo}
    {2}{secundo}
    {3}{tertio}
    %...
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\mynumbering{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\section{Second}
\section{Third}

\end{document}
```

[image]